# How to clear OpenX-hosted cache?

Tags: caching, openx, advertisement-server

well it is easy to set/clear OpenX cache by clearing openx/var/cache directory or by setting cache time by navigating to Configuration > Global Settings > Banner Delivery Settings and set cache time, BUT is it possible to clear cache for the openx-hosted version ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't. You need to be admin... Wait 20 min or install openx on your server.